# data-bind textInput in input type number is not showing the value when I route the site randomly

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, oracle-commerce-cloud

```js
" itemTotal": 300
" orderableQuantity": 981
" orderableQuantityMessage": ""
" originalPrice": 150
" preOrderableQuantity": undefined
" priceChangedMessage": "This item's price has changed since it was added to your cart. Original price was: $150.00 "
" priceListGroupId": "defaultPriceGroup"
" productData": {olapicConfiguration: "9aebf6a8555dafedea6fff54c1c1b399", listVolumePrice: null, x_sLIMFIT: "Fundamental warmth fashioned for everyday.", x_isReversible: false, merchandisingText: null, …}
" productId": "WJM44500C1"
" productPriceChanged": false
" quantity": 2
" rawTotalPrice": 300
" repositoryId": "ci25005140"
" selectedOptions": (2) [{…}, {…}]
" selectedSkuProperties": []
" serviceAccountId": undefined
" serviceId": undefined
" shippingGroupRelationships": [{…}]
" shopperInput": undefined
" skuProperties": undefined
" stockState": "IN_STOCK"
" stockStatus": true
```

Hi I am using Oracle Commerce Cloud platform,
In Cart page for item Quantity I am using input type number in that I have used data-bind Text-input to set the value of the input box,Issue is input box remains empty not every time but if I randomly load and come to cart page

Below js shows the default value that should show every time if i load cart page
For debugging i used the text binding to check if the value is properly setting or not after looking that i end up with it is working fine, something in DOM is effecting it 
Could some one help ??

```js
quantity: ko.observable(1),
```

```html
  <!-- ko if: $data.itemTotal() > 0 -->
                    <input data-bind="textInput : quantity,event:{change:$parentContext.$parent.updateQty}" name="quantity" id="quantityPress" type="number" min="1"> 
                    <div data-bind = "text : quantity"></div>
                    <!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Is it happening when itemTotal =0 on load ? if NO, could you provide your viewModel code related to property you are facing issue.

Comment: NO it doesn't happens when my itemTotal is 0
#Note above i have also added the context related to quantity